# Matlab and MrVista

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and mrVista.

I'm running Matlab Version 7.8.0.347 (R2009a) 32-bit(win32) from February 12, 2009 
OS is Windows 7 Professional
I downloaded the most recent MrVista_hourly.zip and extracted it into my C:\Program_Files_(x86)\MATLAB directory.

I think I need to run mrvInstall, but when I do, I get the following:

```
EDU>> mrvInstall
Checking VISATSOFT installation.
Windows, 32-bit, installation
Checking and possibly installing .NET framework.
This can take several minutes
Checking for visualization library (.dll) files.
You are missing msvcp70.dll.
```

So, I'm completely lost at this point. Do I just need to download msvcp70.dll from the net? If so, is there a *safe* place to download it from? If there's some other way I'm supposed to get mrVista to work from MATLAB, instead of mrvInstall, please let me know that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

EDIT: I've downloaded and installed the dll and still isn't working. I'll go ask on Super User. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

EDIT2: before asking on superuser, I tried once more to solve it myself. Turns out, under the File -> Set Path you have to Add_With_Subfolders the specific vistasoft folder. (Even though I'd already added with subfolders the parent directory where vistasoft lives, that wasn't good enough.) So, once I added the path, and made sure I was in the directory where my data lives, I was able to run the initial command from the tutorial:

```
mrVista inplane
```

It opens up very nicely now. No compiles or installs or other commands were actually necessary. Methinks I'm going to go edit a wiki now so no one else has this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry - I saw related questions about MATLAB which got answered so this didn't seem out of place here. I've checked out the "related question" - don't see anything to fix this, although they are definitely related. I hope someone can answer this newbie question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess "serverfault" is VERY badly named if it's the go-to place for things that have zero to do with servers;-).  Maybe the complaint shd actually point to superuser.com?

Me, I've researched the top google hits for this DLL, the very top one seems to be on "dll-files.com" which has no bad reports I can see and is rated green/safe by mcafee, so that's where I would risk downloading it from.  Weird that I can't find it on a MSFT site, though.

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded and installed the dll.

Comment: mrVista still isn't working but at least I've safely gotten the dll it was asking for.

Comment: Where did you put the dll? Have you run "regsvr32 msvcp70.dll"?

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty comprehensive discussion of Visual C++ runtime DLLs [here](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChToolsMSChain.html)

Whoever built the file that uses msvcp70.dll (and msvcr70.dll) presumably had Visual Studio 2002 and the right to redistribute that file.

You're probably not going to get much help beyond that because I'm a MatLab user and I have no idea what mrVista is.  You've provided no link, no explanation, nothing that someone could use to help you.

Comment: mrVista is used in MATLAB for analysing fMRI data. I would have tagged the question with mrVista as well as MATLAB but wasn't allowed to. I was looking for an answer from someone who's worked with mrVista, as I'm guessing this is something that's pretty familiar to them and to no one else. But thank you for responding with a link to the dll information.

Answer (score 0):

See this page on MrVista Wiki:

http://white.stanford.edu/newlm/index.php/Troubleshooting#MESH

There is information on this dll and where to get it from.

Comment: I tried that troubleshooting FAQ earlier, but thanks for the pointer. Maybe with the dll, it'll work now. I'll be back to let you know.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Oh well. Like I said - I'll go try SuperUser, where I'm told I should have gone at first. Thanks anyway.